# DVD-RW Drive won't read DVDs

Tags: dvd

I have a Samsung R480 running Windows 7, with a DVD-RW drive. It can read CDs fine, but won't read DVDs. It used to be able to read both, but it doesn't do so any more. It would register the DVD every so often, but most of the time, it does the loading thing for a minute or so, then fails. If it helps, the driver lists it as a CD-ROM drive.

Comment: Did you change drivers lately? Revert or reinstall the latest driver.

Comment: I had an NEC drive "die" the same way. unfortunately replacing it was the only way.

Comment: @ngen - no, I tried updating the driver but nothing happened. Option to rollback is disabled. Would uninstalling the driver work?

Comment: @warrenkopp - no idea what NEC means, but I do not want to resort to that.

Comment: It works, but it's hit and miss; sometimes it'll successfully read the DVD, sometimes it won't. I suspect it has something to do with the size.

Comment: I've been having the same problem. But the problematic DVDs are cheap DVD±R's that I burned a few years ago. In my case, I think it may be DVD rot.

Comment: "NEC" is the brand name, like http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827152058 ;-).

Comment: Wonder if the drive has two lasers, one being bad?  Or one laser but it is only partially working - at the wavelength needed to read CD but not DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same problem, I resolved it by bringing it back to Samsung, where they replaced the drive. It took them a bit over a week, mostly cause they were waiting for parts, but partially cause they were having trouble locating the hiccup glitch in my system. It was free cause it was still under warranty, but it sucked that I had to wait that long. Also, I would have liked to credit this answer to warrenkopp, but he posted his response as a comment. Still, thanks for all your responses, especially warrenkopp.